# Trying to find the prime factoring of a number, but it returns nested lists

Tags: python, list, recursion

I'm having some issues with the output of the function to be a pile of nested lists. I'm trying to recursively make a tree of the factors until I end up with only having factors which are primes.

```
def getPrimeFactorHelper(x):
    r = []
    getPrimeFactor(x,r)
    return r

def getPrimeFactor(x,r):
    x = int(x)
    if is_Prime(x) == True:
        r.append(x)
        return r
    z = getLowestFactors(x)
    r.append(getPrimeFactor(z[0],r))
    r.append(getPrimeFactor(z[1],r))
    return r
```

Well currently it gives me the correct numbers as far as I have been able to figure, but its creating nested lists which isn't what I really want as result.

**Outputs:**

(3242) `[2, [...], 1621, [...]]`
the [...]

is the same list again.

Another out where it's even worse:

(48)
`[2, [...], 2, [...], 2, [...], 2, [...], 3, [...], [...], [...], [...]]`

Comment: Instead of `r.append(getPrimeFactor(z[0],r))`, do `r + getPrimeFactor(z[0],r)`. That way you merge the lists instead of appending: [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: I'll put it into an answer if you care to accept it then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `getPrimeFactor()` returns a list, which you then append to your main list, creating the list of lists output you are seeing.

Thus, instead of

`r.append(getPrimeFactor(z[0],r))`

do:

`r + getPrimeFactor(z[0],r)`

That way you concatenate the lists instead of appending: [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html). A good intro to these functions is this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm).

Comment: actually from a bit more of testing on my end the "r +" isn't actually needed.

Comment: also note that if you want to get rid of duplicate items in a list, you can run `set()` on it: [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun here is another approach to finding primes with python/numpy. You can make a pretty simple sieve of eratosthenes:

```
import math
import numpy as np
def sieve_primes(n):

    sieve = np.ones(n/2, dtype=np.bool)  

    i = 3
    while (i**2 < n): 
        if sieve[i/2]:
            sieve[i*i/2 :: i] = False
        i += 2   
    prime_indexes = np.nonzero(sieve)[0][1::]
    primes  = 2 * prime_indexes.astype(np.int32) + 1 
    return primes
```